# SQLite Asset Helper - can't write into my database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to get familiar with the [SQLite Asset Helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) to manage data inside my Android app.

Until now, I've been able to read perfectly from it by using

```
public Cursor getParameters()
    {

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    String [] sqlSelect = { 

            /*0*/ "params0",
            /*1*/ "params1"
            /*2*/ "params2"
            /*3*/ "params3"
    };

    String sqlTables = "settings";

    qb.setTables(sqlTables);
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null,
            null, null, null);

    c.moveToFirst();
    return c;

    }
```

calling it from the `Fragment`:

```
Cursor parameters;
SettingsDataBase db;

// Load the Parameters Database
db = new SettingsDataBase(getActivity());
db.writeData();
parameters = db.getParameters(); // you would not typically call this on the main thread
```

### Problem : I can't write into my database (update data).

Here's what I've done so far:

```
public void writeData()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("REPLACE INTO settings (params0, params1, params2, params3) VALUES ('0', '1', '2','3')");
    }
```

Obviously, no success.

The `execSQL` is running fine, no crashes, but nothing is written inside the database.

Any hints?

Comment: "Obviously, no success" -- what does "no success" mean? Are you crashing?

Comment: The `execSQL` is *executing* fine, no crashes, but nothing is written inside the database. I've tried using `SQLiteStatement` but same results.

Comment: Any thoughts on this?

Comment: How are you determining that nothing is written inside the database? Have you pulled the database off the device or emulator and examined it? Have you tried other statements, such as a plain `INSERT` statement? Beyond that, since this isn't your actual code (e.g., `getParameters()` has Java syntax errors), it is difficult to help you. Here is a sample app that demonstrates `SQLiteAssetHelper` and allows you to modify the resulting database: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Database/ConstantsAssets-AndroidStudio